# Deleting record from sql table and update sql table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to delete a record in sqlite. i have four records record1, record2, record3, record 4
with id as Primary Key.

so it will auto increment for each record that i insert. now when i delete record 3, the primary key is not decrementing. what to do to decrement the id based on the records that i am deleting.

i want id to be 1,2,3 when i delete the record 3 from the database. now it is 1,2,4. Is there any sql query to change it. I tried this one

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE name = ?
```

Note: I am implementing in xcode

Comment: The value of a primary key column has **no meaning** at all. It's only there to uniquely identify a row. If you rely on sepcific values in there (e.g. gapless) then your design is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want this but I would recommend leaving these IDs as is.
What is wrong with having IDs as 1,2,4?
Also you can potentially break things (referential integrity) if you use these ID values as foreign keys somewhere else.

Also please refer to this page to get a better understanding how autoincrement fields works
http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Actually i am deleting an array object based on the id value. for eg. if i delete record 3 then i am using that id(3) to delete object at index 3 in an array.

Comment: if id is not decrementing then array index(id = 4) which will be executed. but the array has only 3 values. so i get a crash.

Comment: Hmmm, bad design. Imagine if you have 1mil row and you want to delete one - do you want to update ~1mil rows to change their IDs?

Comment: What is the purpose of storing your array in the database? Also - as an alternative - can you store the whole array in just 1 record?

Comment: @DmitryK - Not if he wants to add/remove individual items from the 'array'.

Comment: @Dems - this is why I asked what was the purpose. If this is just to persist the state you can easily serialise the whole array into one record.

Comment: DmitryK : i am storing each record in an array. so the when the user delete a item from my app. i am deleting record corresponding to the user id in a database. Main reason for using array is to display the data in my app. so i am deleting corresponding record in my array using user id and then displaying data from the array..

Answer (score 1):

The sense of auto increment is always to create a new unique ID  and not to fill the gaps created by deleting records.

EDIT

You can reach it by a **special table design**. There are no deleted records but with a field "del" marked as deleted.

For example, with a "`select ... where del> 0`" will find all active records.

Or place without the "where" all the records, then the ID's remain unaffected. To loop through an array with "if del = 0 continue". Thus, the array is always in consecutive order.

It's very flexible. Depending on the select ... you get.

- all active records
- all the deleted records
- all records

Comment: Actually i am deleting an array object based on the id value. for eg. if i delete record 3 then i am using that id(3) to delete object at index 3 in an array.

Comment: if id is not decrementing then array index(id = 4) which will be executed. but the array has only 3 values. so i get a crash.

Comment: @Anish - That may be what you *want* to do, but auto-increment does *not* do that in any rdbms that I'm aware of.  Doing so could cause serious referential integrity problems.  You need an alternative solution.  If you post *why* you want to do this, we *may* be able to propose an alternative solution.  What are your use-cases?

Comment: @Dems: i am storing each record in an array. so the when the user delete a item from my app. i am deleting record corresponding to the user id in a database. Main reason for using array is to display the data in my app. so i am deleting corresponding record in my array using user id and then displaying data from the array..